# Calculator in C# like in Perl

Tags: c#, perl, calculator

I want to develop a calculator in C#. I have been programming [Perl](http://learn.perl.org/) a bit. In Perl, I can use [string eval](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) in the following way:

```
while(<STDIN>) {
    $i = $_; chomp($i); unless($i) { last }
    $o = eval($i); print "$i = $o\n";
}
```

With this code, I can enter:

1. (2+2+2)*5
2. cos(5)
3. sqrt(4)

It recognizes a lot of different expressions.

I am not very familiar with C# - so my question is:

Can I do something like the above just in C# instead of Perl?

Comment: cheat method for calculate, using `eval` :)

Comment: Golf: `perl -ple'$_=eval'` ;)

Comment: What is the user types `system "rm -rf /"`?

Comment: @SinanÜnür What if the user types in `rm -rf /` without a perl wrapper?

Comment: @TLP Well, there is a difference between, "here's a shell" versus "here's a calculator". I do not expect a calculator to erase files.

Comment: @SinanÜnür Yes, that would be a fairly reasonable assumption. =P In a real program, I'd expect that some input checking would be in order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not a straight way to do it as in Perl, since C# is a compiled language, it cannot interpret souce code strings on-the-fly.
So, you have at least two alternatives:

- Use an expression evaluator, like the one here: http://flee.codeplex.com or http://ncalc.codeplex.com   There are plenty as well in codeproject.com searching for the phrase "expression evaluator"

  - Compile on-the-fly a code snippet and run it, using C# 4.0 dynamic method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exczf7b9.aspx). Here is a ready-made case: http://www.360doc.com/content/07/0314/20/8309_397508.shtml

Hope this helps

Comment: Perl is compiled too. C#'s inability to do this has nothing with it being compiled.

Comment: @ikegami. From wikipedia: "Perl is a high-level, general-purpose, interpreted, dynamic programming language" and "Perl is implemented as a core interpreter, written in C, together with a large collection of modules". So, as every modern interpreters, it compiles on the fly, that's why it has the "ability" to perform eval. As explained in wikipedia, the compile and execution stages are overlapped.

Comment: Then Wikipedia is wrong. And it's not compiled "on the fly". Compilation happens before the run, just like in C#. Yes, there's a virtual machine involved, but that's not a relevant difference either. I don't know what the relevant difference is, since i don't know why C# doesn't provide such functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, certainly there are options how to do this. Have a look at this for instance:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/CodeDomCalculator08082005003253AM/CodeDomCalculator.aspx